# C++ Исправить функцию, которая складывает символьные строки char!

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, char

Я написала функцию, которая складывает позитивные значения, но если попробовать сложить 1 + 9, в ответе выводится 0, а не 10. Не понимаю, в чем дело, помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту проблему!

И еще, если сможете, добавьте в функцию возможность складывать также отрицательные числа...

Очень нужна ваша помощь, я начинающий в этом и ломаю себе голову уже очень и очень долго в поискать решения этой задачи :(

```
void summ(char* a, char* b, char* c) {
  int a_len = strlen(a), b_len = strlen(b);
  int a_tmp = a_len - 1, b_tmp = b_len - 1, tmp, r = 0, digit;

  for (int i = 0; i < max(a_len, b_len) + 1; ++i) {


   tmp = ((a[a_tmp] - '0') + (b[b_tmp] - '0')) + r;
   if (b_tmp < 0)
       tmp = (a[a_tmp] - '0') + r;
   if (a_tmp < 0)
       tmp = (b[b_tmp] - '0') + r;

   if (tmp > 9) {
       digit = tmp % 10;
       c[i] = digit + '0';
       r = 1;
   }
   else {
       r = 0;
       c[i] = tmp + '0';
   }
   a_tmp--;
   b_tmp--;
  }
}

int main() {
   int T;
   char a[n];
   char b[n];
   char c[n];
   do {
       cin >> a;
       cin >> b;
       summ(a, b, c);
       for (int i = strlen(c) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
           cout << c[i];
      }
       cout << "\nПродолжить - 1, закончить - 0." << endl;
       cin >> T;

   } while (T == 1);
 }
```

Comment: как-то вы усложнили задачу сложения в столбик - больше действий, чем требуется

Comment: в общем случаи, сначала нужно проверять  может ли строка представить число и учитывать начальные и конечные пробелы. Ведь может быть строка к примеру такая: `"   -  3425   "`(в С++ удобно пользоваться `std::string_view `), результирующая строка должна иметь длину на один больше, чтобы добавить единицу, если сумма первых чисел  не меньше чем 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а вот так работает:

```
void summ(char* a, char* b, char* c) {
    const int a_len = strlen(a);
    const int b_len = strlen(b);

    int overflow = 0;

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < std::max(a_len, b_len); i++) 
    {
        // получить цифры числа a и числа b
        const int digit_a = (i < a_len) ? (a[a_len - 1 - i] - '0') : 0;
        const int digit_b = (i < b_len) ? (b[b_len - 1 - i] - '0') : 0;

        // вычислить цифру числа c
        const int res = digit_a + digit_b + overflow;
        overflow = res / 10;

        // записать цифру в число c
        c[i] = '0' + (res % 10);
    }

    // учесть бит переполнения
    if (overflow != 0)
        c[i++] = '0' + overflow;

    // закрыть строку
    c[i] = 0;

    // перевернуть строку (число было записано в обратном порядке)
    _strrev(c);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, вы очень помогли! Я еще совсем новенькая в этом, иногда бывает сложно написать просто и красиво и изобретаю самолет там, где этого не просят.. (причем не работающий). Я совсем обнаглею, но хочу попросить вас помочь с реализацией такого же сложения, но еще и отрицательных чисел.. то есть дополнить эту функцию, чтобы она считала также сумму отрицательных чисел, тут я совсем не знаю, как это реализовать..

Comment: пишете такую же функцию, только с вычитанием, потом вычитаете из большего числа меньшее, затем ставите соответствующий знак, т.е. для отрицательных чисел не надо ваять какой-то специальный код, лучше реализовать сложение, вычитание, сравнение и всё - этими операциями дальше можно делать все остальное